# Present Perfect in the future

Tags: present-perfect

There was a sentence that needed to be completed in an English test that  confused me.

> I/certainly/need/rest/after/my/cousins/back/Canada.

My solution was:

> I will certainly need some rest after my cousins **have gone back** to Canada.

The others' was:

> I will certainly need some rest after my cousins **go back** to Canada.

I'm wondering if present perfect (have gone) can be used in this sentence because I feel like the author can only get some rest after his cousins have gone back to Canada.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Both your suggestions are fine.

*Have gone* is, as you suggest, more accurate, and is what I would probably use in writing.

In speech, English speakers often do not use "have" forms when the temporal relationships are clear without them, so *go* is  probably what I would say in informal speech.

Answer (score 0):

- I will certainly need some rest after my cousins have gone back to Canada.
- or: go back to Canada.

Present prefect here shows completion or a finished action. Both are correct. There is a slight difference in meaning.

One is simultaneous (simple present) and the other is completion (present perfect).

The gentleman in the video explains it very well.

[difference between simple past and present perfect after when, after, etc.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3_cUjPaHbY0)